# Comparing dates/times - PHP, XML, strtotime

Tags: php, xml, datetime, conditional-statements, strtotime

Stack Overflow Community,

I have always appreciated your wisdom and assistance. Here is my situation:

Here is a snippet of my XML file (this is a very small portion of it):

```
    <matchup id="1" date="09/08/11" time="7:30 PM">
        <away city="New Orleans">Saints</away>
        <home city="Green Bay">Packers</home>
        <finalscore>
            <away></away>
            <home></home>
        </finalscore>
    </matchup>
```

Okay, so using SimpleXML I am getting this XML data and storing it into respective PHP variables. The only thing I really need help with is the date/time section.

I am wanting to basically compare the date/time of the matchup to the current time. If the time of the matchup has already passed (or started for that matter), I want to display a different output.

So here is my PHP, but something is not working correctly here:

```
foreach($week->matchup as $matchup)
{
$game_time = $matchup['time'];
$game_date = $matchup['date'];

date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$game_date2 = strtotime($game_date);
$game_date3 = date('m/d/y', $game_date2);
$time_stamp = strtotime($game_time);
$check = date("g:i A", $time_stamp);
$date_now = date('m/d/y');
$time_now = date('g:i A');

if ($game_date3 >= $date_now && $check >= $time_now) {

?>
<tr>
<td class="two"><?php echo $game_date ?></td>
<td class="two">
<input type="radio" id="<?php echo $away_city ?> <?php echo $away_teamname ?>" class="radio" name="<?php echo $week_name ?>" value="<?php echo $away_city ?> <?php echo $away_teamname ?>"></input>
    <?php echo $away_full ?>
</td>
<td class="two">
<input type="radio" id="<?php echo $home_city ?> <?php echo $home_teamname ?>" class="radio" name="<?php echo $week_name ?>" value="<?php echo $home_city ?> <?php echo $home_teamname ?>"></input>
    <?php echo $home_full ?>
</td>
<td class="two"><?php echo $game_time ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
} else {
?>
<tr>
<td class="two"><?php echo $game_date ?></td>
<td class="two">
<span><?php echo $away_full ?></span>
</td>
<td class="two">
<span><?php echo $home_full ?></span>
</td>
<td class="two"><?php echo $game_time ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
    } ?>
```

As you can see here, what I am trying to do is simply check if the date/time from the XML is past the time of the current time. If it is, I want to display an output WITHOUT input radio buttons. If it is not past the current time, I want to display the output WITH input radio buttons.

I think the problem is somewhere in my variable setting with strtotime and getting the XML date/time to parse properly against the server time.

I hope someone can help me figure this out! Also, any recommendations to make this more concise and secure is appreciated as well.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking then... What does the syntax look like to do that?

I would take the date/time from the XML... Convert it to a PHP variable and use strtotime to crunch them into timestamps... Then I take that timestamp and compare it to the current timestamp? Is that what you saying? Thanks for the advice... Keep it coming :)

Comment: You're a stud, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare date strings. You need to convert them to timestamps using `strtotime` **then** compare them.

Like this:

```
$date = '09/08/11 7:30 PM';

if (strtotime($date) < time()) {
    // $date is in the past
}
```

So in your case:

```
$game_time = $matchup['time'];
$game_date = $matchup['date'];
$date = "{$game_date} {$game_time}";

if (strtotime($date) < time()) {
    // $date is in the past
}
```

Comment: I have confidence that what you just mocked up for me is going to work. Sounds logical and correct. I will know once I plug it in! :) I am going to pre-emptively say you are my hero.

Comment: THIS SOLUTION WORKED! YOU ARE MY HERO. I CAN SAY FOR A FACT. YOU ARE A BEAST!

Comment: If it works for you, don't declare me a hero, upvote and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would caution against using the older date functions and suggest that you use the DateTime class. For the above you should be looking at [`DateTime::createFromFormat();`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

So you would have something like this:

```
$game_date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $game_date);
$game_date3 = new DateTime();

if($game_date2 > $game_date3) {
    echo 'game yet to be played';
}
```

Note you need at least PHP5.2.2 to be able to compare date objects like have in my code above. See the [DateTime::diff() page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-596) for more information.

Comment: Are you saying the older date functions are what is possibly causing me troubles with the parsing of the date/time from the XML?

Comment: Okay, so since you added the code...

the new DateTime() will get the current time? So $game_date3 is the current time...

Will the DateTime::createFromFormat parse my XML data properly and work for comparing? I guess I will have to give this a shot to know.

Comment: @JohnStamos Please see my edited answer in which I have provided and example. I prefer to be explicit about the format I am converting a date from. As for using DateTime it is a good habit to get into in my opinion as it is more flexible.

Comment: `createFromFormat()` takes a defined format string that describes what the various aspects of the date mean (the reverse of `date()` effectively). So as long as the format string I have mocked above matches the format of your dates then yes it will work.